# Hibernate - how to catch "integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation"

Tags: hibernate, exception, rollback, unique-constraint, hibernateexception

In my table I have a unique constraint.
In hibernate, when I add an item that violates that constraint, I want to catch it, so It will update instead of create an item.

When I set no try-catch block around

```
    updated = query.executeUpdate();
```

it gets following error

```
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation: WEEKROOSTERITEMUNI
```

When I set the following try-catch block

```
    try {
        updated = query.executeUpdate();

     }    
   catch(PersistenceException e){                                                         
        LOG.debug("this is PersistenceException exception throw");      
    }
```

it gets the following error

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

When I catch "ConstraintViolationException" I just keep getting the constraint exception, it doesn't catch anything.

```
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation: WEEKROOSTERITEMUNI
```

How can I catch this?

Comment: Suggest to go through this link in SO

[SO Link][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167730/checks-for-constraint-violation-before-persisting-an-entity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `RollbackException` is thrown at a higher level because `@Transactional` is set in that higher lever, so you can't catch it on that level. You need to catch it in the layer of your transaction.

A better way is to do a check if the object already exists on the database layer. A check-function.
That check function is a get by the unique constraints. This is better because you don't need to catch exceptions.

You already need that get-function of the object, because you later want to merge that object. You don't want to merge a detached instance.

Comment: This doesn't work in the face of concurrent access to the database.  Between the time you check and the time yo do something else, another session may have changed the database state.

Answer (score 0):

To catch unique constraint you should catch this exception ConstraintViolationException

Comment: When I do this, it doesn't catch anything, I just keep getting "Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation: WEEKROOSTERITEMUNI"

Comment: Did you try to catch HibernateException?

Comment: I catch it with a DataIntegrityViolationException exception